# Are Way of Fire Kolduns more resistant to Rotschreck?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Mastering the Koldunic sorcery school of the Way of Fire seems to come with an obvious drawback - seeing fire so often would probably do a lot of unpleasantness to the Cainite performing it. Is there a canon explanation to whether it would?

Comment: Is there a specific edition of *VtM* that you're interested in? I would guess V20, but clarifying may result in better answers.

Comment: I've actually tagged this V5, but I'd be delighted to also hear the V20 one. Should I remove the tag?

Comment: Hm, I don't see the V5 tag. But adding V20 as well as V5 might allow for answers from both (other users are more knowledgeable about tag best-practices than I am).

Comment: So, the Kolduns and their magic haven't been brought to V5 yet; at this time, there's no answer in that edition, because the circumstance isn't there. No Tzimisce at all have been published so far. *Cult of the Blood Gods* may have more to say.

Comment: @Upper_Case Funny enough, I can't find the V20 tag anywhere in my previous questions about VtM. Did it get lost somewhere?

Comment: @IvanT.: I don't think there is a tag for V20 specifically. The only mention of such a tag possibly existing that I've seen is in this meta: [Should we add V20/M20 etc tags for White Wolf Games?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/should-we-add-v20-m20-etc-tags-for-white-wolf-games) (...which was closed as a duplicate of: [Clean up tagging for “World of Darkness” related questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/clean-up-tagging-for-world-of-darkness-related-questions))

Comment: I don't know enough about VtM to know whether such a tag would be justified/needed, but if you're unsure and/or you think you can make a case for it, you could make a post on [meta] (and potentially answer it with your own case for why such a tag should exist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

I'm reading the question as *do Way of Fire Koldunic sorcerers have access to any bonuses which directly make resisting Rötschrek easier?*

A one-dot power available through the *Way of Fire*, called *Fiery Courage*, does this directly:

> #### • Fiery Courage
>
> No vampire can master an element he fears, so this power
>   dims that fear to a mere ember of its former intensity.
>
> **System:** Once learned, this power is permanent and
>   requires no activation roll or blood. The koldun subtracts
>   his rating in the Way of Fire from the difficulty
>   of Courage rolls to resist Rötschreck from exposure or
>   proximity to flame. This power does not aid in resisting
>   the panic that accompanies sunlight or any other
>   causes apart from actual fire. If this reduces the difficulty
>   of a Courage roll below two, the koldun simply
>   does not succumb to the Red Fear. Koldun never risk
>   Rötschrek from fire and magma they conjure. (*Core Rulebook, V20, p. 452*)

_

Otherwise, a high Courage rating is of use in resisting Rötschrek and so a Koldunic sorcerer of this type would probably have (or develop) a high Courage rating (if they're planning to be around fires caused by other means).

Finally, not all fires are created equal. *Way of Fire* offers a variety of abilities based on hot things, like magma, but little to no effects that directly produce a fire (though they could ignite other things). That helps a lot, since a fire indirectly caused by their use of the Discipline is probably not going to start out as a conflagration.

A lighter-sized flame used to light a cigarette is pretty easy to dismiss, and a bonfire represents some Rötschrek risk but hardly a guaranteed one. Especially with *Fiery Courage*, a *Way of Fire* koldun is likely to be well-equipped to deal with any fires of any kind that they might encounter in their work.